# merge in sqlserver - incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I try to execute this transaction:

```
GO
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE A AS t 
USING B AS tmp
ON (t.domain = tmp.domain and t.link=tmp.link) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY A
    THEN INSERT(ipVal, domain, dateStart, dateUpdate, dateFinish, link) VALUES(tmp.ipVal, tmp.domain, tmp.dateStart, tmp.dateUpdate, tmp.dateFinish, tmp.link)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET t.dateupdate = tmp.dateupdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY B
    THEN UPDATE SET t.datefinish="a"
ROLLBACK TRAN;
GO
```

I took this code from [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx), But when I tried to execute this I got an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'A'
```

What can be the problem?

Comment: An understandable mistake, since the Technet page you linked to uses `Target` and `Source` as names for the example tables, thus mixing them with the `TARGET` and `SOURCE` keywords.

Answer (score 6):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) the simplified syntax for `WHEN NOT MATCHED` branches is

```
   [ WHEN NOT MATCHED [ BY TARGET ] [...]
        THEN <merge_not_matched> ]
    [ WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE [...]
        THEN <merge_matched> ] [ ...n ]
```

The solution is to replace `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY A` with `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY B` with `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`.

`TARGET` and `SOURCE` are T-SQL keywords not placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

One I just began to use MERGE I use this syntax to understand it right:

```
MERGE A AS target
USING B AS source
ON (target.domain = source.domain and target.link=source.link) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT(ipVal, domain, dateStart, dateUpdate, dateFinish, link)
    VALUES(source.ipVal, source.domain, source.dateStart, source.dateUpdate, source.dateFinish, source.link)
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET target.dateupdate = source.dateupdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
    THEN UPDATE SET target.datefinish="a"
```

I know it is a bad practice but when started - helps a lot.

As @BogdanSahlean points `TARGET` and `SOURCE` are keywords and there are required when you determine matched/not matched statements.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to update the date or datetime type column with char or varchar type data which is not convertible to date or datetime type. 'a' is not convertible to date or datetime. Look at the First and the second Merge I have below.If you don't mention when matched or when not matched  by source or target, by default it considers Target.

```
--DROP TABLE #A;
--DROP TABLE #B;

CREATE TABLE #A
    (
        ipval VARCHAR(50)
    , domain CHAR(5)
    , dateStart DATE
    , dateUpdate DATE
    , dateFinish DATE
    , link VARCHAR(50)
    );

CREATE TABLE #B
    (
        ipval VARCHAR(50)
    , domain CHAR(5)
    , dateStart DATE
    , dateUpdate DATE
    , dateFinish DATE
    , link VARCHAR(50)
    );
INSERT  INTO #B
        ( ipval, domain, dateStart, dateUpdate, dateFinish, link )
VALUES  ( '42.130.239.56'  -- ipval - varchar(50)
            , '.com'  -- domain - char(5)
            , GETDATE()  -- dateStart - date
            , DATEADD(DAY, 1, GETDATE())  -- dateUpdate - date
            , DATEADD(DAY, 5, GETDATE())  -- dateFinish - date
            , 'www.stackoverflow'  -- link - varchar(50)
            ),
        ( '78.188.136.74'  -- ipval - varchar(50)
            , '.com'  -- domain - char(5)
            , GETDATE()  -- dateStart - date
            , DATEADD(DAY, 2, GETDATE())  -- dateUpdate - date
            , DATEADD(DAY, 10, GETDATE())  -- dateFinish - date
            , 'www.msdn'  -- link - varchar(50)
            );

INSERT  INTO #A
        ( ipval, domain, dateStart, dateUpdate, dateFinish, link )
VALUES  ( '30.48.111.20'  -- ipval - varchar(50)
            , '.com'  -- domain - char(5)
            , GETDATE()  -- dateStart - date
            , DATEADD(DAY, 5, GETDATE())  -- dateUpdate - date
            , DATEADD(DAY, 10, GETDATE())  -- dateFinish - date
            , 'www.msdn'  -- link - varchar(50)
            ),
        ( '30.48.111.20'  -- ipval - varchar(50)
            , '.com'  -- domain - char(5)
            , GETDATE()  -- dateStart - date
            , DATEADD(DAY, 5, GETDATE())  -- dateUpdate - date
            , DATEADD(DAY, 10, GETDATE())  -- dateFinish - date
            , 'www.gmail'  -- link - varchar(50)
            );
--First Merge
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE #A AS T
USING #B AS tmp
ON T.domain = tmp.domain
    AND T.link = tmp.link
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ( ipval
            , domain
            , dateStart
            , dateUpdate
            , dateFinish
            , link
            )
    VALUES ( tmp.ipval
            , tmp.domain
            , tmp.dateStart
            , tmp.dateUpdate
            , tmp.dateFinish
            , tmp.link
            )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET T.dateUpdate = tmp.dateUpdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    UPDATE SET T.dateFinish =''a'';
COMMIT TRAN;
GO


SELECT  *
FROM    #A;
SELECT  *
FROM    #B;
--Second Merge
BEGIN TRAN;
MERGE #A AS T
USING #B AS tmp
ON T.domain = tmp.domain
    AND T.link = tmp.link
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
    INSERT ( ipval
           , domain
           , dateStart
           , dateUpdate
           , dateFinish
           , link
           )
    VALUES ( tmp.ipval
           , tmp.domain
           , tmp.dateStart
           , tmp.dateUpdate
           , tmp.dateFinish
           , tmp.link
           )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET T.dateUpdate = tmp.dateUpdate
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
    UPDATE SET T.dateFinish = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE);
COMMIT TRAN;
GO


SELECT  *
FROM    #A;
SELECT  *
FROM    #B;
```